# Arch linux xfce4 with catalyst

Tags: arch-linux, radeon, xfce

I've recently installed xfce4 (switched from gnome3) as well as the Catalyst driver. I have quite a powerful computer along with quite a powerful graphics card (radeon 6950) however a lot of the features I want don't work. For example: terminal transparency does not work, and the mouse fragments sometimes when I move between monitors. I've been experimenting with the ATI control center settings, but nothing seems to fix this. I'd like to know if there are some optimisations I could look into (I already looked at the Catalyst page on the arch linux wiki) that would make my experience better. The reason I switched to catalyst from the opensource driver is so that I can run opencl apps, so the opensource driver is not an option.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you have to manually enable the internal composer in XFCE4, this has nothing to do with your VGA drivers.

go in

```
Settings > Xfce 4 Settings Manager > Window Manager Tweaks
```

Comment: i did this, it causes transparency to not work altogether! (before it was transparent, but only ever showed the desktop behind it)

Comment: @mikhailvs what is supposed to show behind in your case?

Comment: the window that is behind it. but again, turning on the compositor makes it not transparent at all

Comment: @mikhailvs ok, i have to ask that, did you move the sliders in that tab?

Comment: no, I don't need those to be anything other than opaque...

Comment: Also, in response to the "has nothing to do with your VGA drivers," this feature worked before I changed the driver...